# Extract JSON Values in Snowflake SQL

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create two columns from a column of values containing JSON in Snowflake using SQL.

Say this table is called keywords_bids
then there is a column called **keywords** that has JSON in it 
example json in a cell in the keywords column:
row1: **{"apple":0.1, "peach":0.2, "banana":0.1}** row2: similar JSON, etc....
[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGYcM.png)
I want to create a columns called keyword and it is bid price from the JSON
output would be: 
keyword | Bid 
'apple' | 0.1
'peach' | 0.2
'banana'| 0.3

Answer (score 1):

First for JSON you'll need to change the single quotes to double quotes.

Then you just need to flatten the json to get keys and values:

```sql
with data as (
select parse_json('{"apple":0.1, "peach":0.2, "banana":0.1}') j
)

select k.key, k.value
from data, table(flatten(j)) k
;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising but I cannot hard code the values for each row. Could you give a method to convert the JSON from a column called keywords from keyword_bid table? each row in the column keywords is a JSON like the one in the question.

Comment: There's nothing hard coded, but the sample data so the example would work.

Answer (score 0):

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dynamically-extracting-JSON-using-LATERAL-FLATTEN

This article is to demonstrate various examples of using LATERAL FLATTEN to extract information from a JSON Document. Examples are provided for its utilization together with GET_PATH, UNPIVOT, and SEQ functions.

Answer (score 0):

##### Easy way to get values from JSON in snowflake

---

For example:
Table: ABC
Column: Json_column it contain JSON content like

```json
 "carriers": [
        {
          "code": "AAAA",
          "flightNumber": "XXXX",
          "type": "OPERATING"
        },
        {
          "code": "BBBB",
          "flightNumber": "YYYY",
          "type": "MARKETING"
        }
      ]
```

```
SELECT Json_column:carriers[0].code::varchar AS first_child,
Json_column:carriers[1].code::varchar AS first_childFROM ABC;
```

Result of SQL will be

> AAAA, BBBB

As data is in array we are using [0] and [1] getting the value of JSON.