# Extract value from JSON array using Snowflake sql

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake table has a varchar column with following JSON array as value.

`[{"$":6394.2,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 1"},{"$":6672.25,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 2"},{"$":5643.05,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 3"},{"$":5564.79,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 4"},{"$":6966.75,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 5"},{"$":7605.15,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 6"}]`

Using snowflake sql, I would like to extract data in following format.

```
Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4,Month5,Month6
6394.2,6672.25,5643.05,5564.79,6966.75,7605.15
```

I was trying to implement solution  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77319223/20535715 , but my json is organized differently.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing? Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Comment: figured out how to use index position, it works with a query as blow,

```
WITH sample_data AS (
SELECT
  PARSE_JSON('[
    {"$": 63694.1, "@": "t1"},
    {"$": 63694.2, "@": "t2"},
    {"$": 63694.3, "@": "t3"}
  ]') AS json_data
)
SELECT
 json_data[0]."$",
 json_data[1]."$",
 json_data[2]."$"
FROM sample_data;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one. I write it assuming that you may have multiple rows:

```
with mytable as (
select ('[{"$":6394.2,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 1"},{"$":6672.25,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 2"},{"$":5643.05,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 3"},{"$":5564.79,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 4"},{"$":6966.75,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 5"},{"$":7605.15,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 6"}]' ) x
union all
select ('[{"$":6394.3,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 1"},{"$":6672.25,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 2"},{"$":5643.05,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 3"},{"$":5564.79,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 4"},{"$":6966.75,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 5"},{"$":7605.15,"@":"decisionMetricValue","@id":"Month 6"}]' ) x
),
flattened as (
select 
v.seq row_num,
get( v.value, '@id' )::VARCHAR colname,
get( v.value, '$' ) monvalue
from mytable,
lateral flatten (  PARSE_JSON(x) )  v
)
select * from flattened
pivot (sum(monvalue) for colname In ('Month 1','Month 2','Month 3','Month 4','Month 5'))
order by row_num
;
```

This is the result:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ROW_NUM | 'Month 1' | 'Month 2' | 'Month 3' | 'Month 4' | 'Month 5' |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 |    6394.2 |   6672.25 |   5643.05 |   5564.79 |   6966.75 |
|       2 |    6394.3 |   6672.25 |   5643.05 |   5564.79 |   6966.75 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Add the following immediately after the PIVOT clause to format the column headers: AS P (Row_Num,Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4,Month5,Month6)

Answer (score 1):

Had to use  use index position differently, it works with a query as blow,

```
 WITH sample_data AS (
    SELECT
      PARSE_JSON('[
        {"$": 63694.1, "@": "t1"},
        {"$": 63694.2, "@": "t2"},
        {"$": 63694.3, "@": "t3"}
      ]') AS json_data
    )
    SELECT
     json_data[0]."$",
     json_data[1]."$",
     json_data[2]."$"
    FROM sample_data;
```